# I can't wrap my head around this short Python code. Could someone ELI5 or give directions?

Tags: python, lambda, nested, list-comprehension, decorator

```
def fun():
    return[lambda x:i*x for i in range(3)]
for f in fun():
    print(f(1),end='')
```

What I can understand that fun() returns 3 functions which multiply given argument by 0,1,2.
Then f represents each function(lambda) and gives it argument value of 1.

Basically the answear should be:
012

But the anwear is:
 222.

Is this becouse all lambdas are instances? I even checked, returned lambdas in f doesnt have the same address so they are not instances?

I'm surely missing something but I dont know in which direction I should look for the answear.
List comprehension? Lambdas? Decorators?

Answer (score 3):

There is an explanation in [common gotchas](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#id1).

> Python’s closures are late binding. This means that the values of
> variables used in closures are looked up at the time the inner
> function is called.
>
> Here, whenever any of the returned functions are called, the value of
> `i` is looked up in the surrounding scope at call time. By then, the
> loop has completed and `i` is left with its final value of 2.

You can solve it by binding `i` as default argument for each function

```
def fun():
    return [lambda x, i=i: i * x for i in range(3)]
```